# How to give child nodes an 'id' with JSON in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jstree

I've got a tree which has been populated through JSON like so (please excuse the formatting):

```
$("#treeView").jstree({
          "themes": {
              "theme": "default",
                "dots": false,
                  "icons": false
                   },
           "json_data": {
                "data": [
        {
        "data": "2011",
        "metadata": { id: 2011 },
        "children": [

{ "data": "January", "attributes": { "id": "jan_2011"} },
{ "data": "February", "attributes": { "id": "feb_2011"} },
{ "data": "March", "attributes": { "id": "mar_2011"} },
{ "data": "April", "attributes": { "id": "apr_2011"} },
{ "data": "May", "attributes": { "id": "may_2011"} },   
{ "data": "June", "attributes": { "id": "jun_2011"} },
{ "data": "July", "attributes": { "id": "jul_2011"} },
{ "data": "August", "attributes": { "id": "aug_2011"} },
{ "data": "September", "attributes": { "id": "sep_2011"} },
{ "data": "October", "attributes": { "id": "oct_2011"} },
{ "data": "November", "attributes": { "id": "nov_2011"} },
{ "data": "December", "attributes": { "id": "dec_2011"} }
]
                }]
                    },
                    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
                }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                    alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id"));
                });
            });
```

My problem is that whenever a node is clicked, the alert box does not display anything, or simply 'undefined'. In other words, I think the 'id' attributes are not being set for the children nodes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried actually looking at the DOM with the Chrome debugger or Firebug to see what the generated HTML elements look like?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, the id attribute is not present in the html code. However, it is not present for the parent nodes either, which is strange as when I click on a parent node, the id does appear in the alert box. It's the children's 'id' that aren't displaying.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsTree, but assuming that this is creating a DOM structure, you appear to be assigning the same id to multiple elements, which is illegal.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use "attr" instead of "attributes". Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/DUYU6/) link.

Comment: Thanks Luffy > Simply use **"attr"** instead of **"attributes"**. Here is the jsfiddle link. Worked for me after hours of search and disappointment, as I was using 'attributes' in my JSON data.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same situation i.e. Using JSON data-source and unable to get the id with a pretty simple and straight forward statement that is even mentioned in the site documentation ( btw, I personally feel that the documentation of jsTree is not up to the mark of its highly loaded features)

```
alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id"));
```

after hours of searching and point by point debugging the difference was figured out to be a single word. Use **attr** instead of full word **attributes** i.e.

```
{ "data": "January", "attr": { "id": "jan_2011"} },
```